# How can I save data to mysql in codeigniter from a foreach input field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can i save data to mysql in codeigniter from a foreach input field.I want to save all these value in MySQL. Score field should be linked with student id field. How can I do that ?

```
<tbody>                 
    <?php if (!empty($all_student_record_info)): foreach ($all_student_record_info as $v_student_record) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="student_id[]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->student_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->student_id ; ?></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="school_id[]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->school_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->school_name ?></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="class_id[]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->class_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->classes_name ?></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="section_id[]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->section_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->section_name ?></td>                                
                <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_father_name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_contact_number ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_address ?></td>                                
                <td><input type="text" name="score[]"></td>                              
            </tr>
            <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <td colspan="3">
        <strong>There is no data to display</strong>
    </td>
<?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: So what you want is , insert all the dataarray object `$all_student_record_info` into your MySQL database ?

Comment: Do you want to add data in your controller or view ?

Comment: yes in controller and save to mysql

Comment: @LEARNER have you taken any form whose action leads to the controller ?

Comment: Have you checked my answer @LEARNER ?

Answer (score 0):

First you should Do this on your controller

```
  $data = $this->yourModel->yourfunction()->result(); 

   foreach($data as $data){ 
   $array = array(
        'yourtablecolumn' => $data->student_id,
        'youttablecolumn => $data->student_id,
    ),
    $insert = $this->db->insert('yourtable',$array);
   if($insert){
       echo 'Succes';
   }else{
      echo 'No';
   }

}
```